# NHibernate mapping by code + polymorphism

Tags: nhibernate, mapping, polymorphism

I use NH 3.2 and Mapping by code in my project.
Today I try to set explicit polymorphism to some entities, but can't find how?
I know how to set it in .hbm or FNH, but not in Mapping by code!
Anybody can help me out?

Comment: So, if I right understand in Mapping by code there is no way to set polymorphism :( 
As a workaround I do the following trick: 
`code`
       var fluentMapping = mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities();

       foreach (var rootClass in fluentMapping.RootClasses)
       {
           if (rootClass.Name.StartsWith("CashDepartment.Server.DomainModel.Enities.Staff"))
               rootClass.polymorphism = HbmPolymorphismType.Explicit;
       }

       NHConfiguration.AddMapping(fluentMapping);
`code`

Comment: So, if I right understand in Mapping by code there is no way to set polymorphism :( 
As a workaround I do the following trick: 
`
       var fluentMapping = mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities();

       foreach (var rootClass in fluentMapping.RootClasses)
       {
           if (rootClass.Name.StartsWith("CashDepartment.Server.DomainModel.Enities.Staff"))
               rootClass.polymorphism = HbmPolymorphismType.Explicit;
       }

       NHConfiguration.AddMapping(fluentMapping);
`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are correct; explicit polymorphism setting from mapping-by-code has not been implemented yet.

If this is important to you, open a jira issue at http://nhibernate.jira.com